# The different output of polynomial regression in python and R

Tags: python, r, regression

I use python and R to do the three-order polynomial regression, but the obtained coefficients are different, I do not know the reason, and code seem to be right.

Python code:

```py
def poly_three(n):
    polynomial_features= PolynomialFeatures(degree=3)
    data =polynomial_features.fit_transform(np.array(boston[n]).reshape(-1,1))
    model = sm.OLS(boston['CRIM'], data).fit()
    return model.summary()

ZN, INDUS, CHAS, NOX, RM, AGE, DIS, RAD, TAX, PTRATIO, B, LSTAT, Y = boston.keys()[1:14]

poly_three('ZN')
```

R code:

```py
fit.zn2 <- lm(crim ~ poly(zn, 3))
summary(fit.zn2)
```

Python result:

coefficients: 4.8461; -0.3322; 0.0065; -3.776e-05

R result:

coefficients: 3.6135; -38.7498 ; 23.9398 ; -10.0719

Comment: [`lm` from R uses QR factorization](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.1/topics/lm) to solve the least square minimization, while [`OLS.fit()` uses Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse by default](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.fit.html#statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.fit). Try at least using `fit(method="qr")`.

Comment: I tried it. The outcome remind the same.

Comment: Then maybe you will need to post more details to be able to reproduce the computations. All settings equal, potentially the implementation details, like the choice of pivots or stopping tolerances, could lead to different results. The results in your case are quite different, though. It looks like both implementations can output the model matrix and the QR factorization. You could also print and compare those as a starting point.

Comment: It would be ideal to see or have more info w.r.t. the input/response data.  Also, another function you can try from `numpy` is `polyfit`.